# ALL labels in my project returns NULL even if it contains value

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Starting from today, all my labels returns null for some reason.

Tried reinstalling Visual studio, downgrade to random version of xamarin.form/essentials. Trying the same code on different PC. Same issue.

Codes of one of my page:

XAML:

```
    <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollView">
            <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20">
                <Label Text="Drugs Name:" FontSize="Small" />
                <Label Text="{Binding DrugsName}" d:Text="Drug Name" FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Text="Nick Name:" FontSize="Small" />
                <Label Text="{Binding NickName}" d:Text="Drug Nick Name" FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Text="Expiry Date:" FontSize="Small" />
                <Label Text="{Binding ExpiryDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd,yyyy}'}" d:Text="Quantity" FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Text="Note:" FontSize="Small"/>
 Note Label ---->      <Label Text="{Binding Note}" x:Name="lblnotes" d:Text="Note" FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Text="Location Image:" FontSize="Small"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding image_path}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

CS:

```
    public StorageDetailsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

// checking if note contains nothing, if nothing returns N/A

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lblnotes.Text) == true)
            {
                lblnotes.Text = "N/A";
            }
        }
```

It was fine in my development progress, whole project just bugged out today.

Images:

[Debugging returns null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZoC.png)

[Commented out and shows not null in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcly9.png)

Comment: where are you setting the BindingContext?  What is your ViewModel?  You are testing the values in the constructor, at that point the data binding logic has not been executed so the UI elements won't contain values.  In your 2nd screenshot you are setting your BindingContext to a generic object instead of a strongly typed class, which is odd.

Comment: Was the data binding logic not executed at the BindingContext()? Whole project was working the day before, it didn’t work since yesterday without me making any changes

Answer (score 0):

**The reason is not binding data for ContentPage** .

```
public StorageDetailsPage(object obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = obj;  // not missing this in ContentPage         

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lblnotes.Text) == true)
        {
            lblnotes.Text = "N/A";
        }
    }
```

From second shared image , you will see that not null . Because it setted `BindingContext = obj;` , however the first image not doing that .

Modifying code as follow to check :

```
public StorageDetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new YourViewModel();  // bind a ViewModel here to check         
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lblnotes.Text) == true)
        {
            lblnotes.Text = "N/A";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I’ll try but I doubt it is the problem, my whole project has the same problem while it was fine the day before

Comment: @Long Okey , I also have a doubt about the two shared image with different `StorageDetailsPage` constructor  method  in project . Which one used in your project ?

Comment: The first one, the second constructor with (object obj) is a dummy, I should have deleted them actually. From the second image you can see the cursor is at the end of the first constructor } (commented out constuctor)

Comment: @Long You can share the method code about navigating to `StorageDetailsPage` ,that will be helpful .It depends how to navigate to `StorageDetailsPage` .If contain `object` when navigating to `StorageDetailsPage` , you will get data . However , if no ,there will no data .